# Driver for libvirt or new hypervisor

Tags: driver, openstack, hpc, libvirt

I must say that I do not know English very well. Therefore, I write through Google translator. So, the problem is the following, I have a system that parallels the tasks, it looks like something on SLURM, it is necessary to run tasks using this system through the cloud (openstack). You need to write your hypervisor, that is, this system will be used as a hypervisor, and as a virtual machine there will be a task that needs to be parallelized. The question is, how do I write a driver for libvirt and screw it to openstack? It turns out this driver will be like an abstraction, an interlayer for openstack, so that you can understand the commands for this system through the cloud. Maybe there are some manuals that describe how to write your driver for libvirt, a description of classes, methods, at least something.